# using localization files in library

Tags: localization, xamarin.ios

i have a component library. i created en.lproj folder and Localizable.strings,Library.strings file in this folder. i do this also for my main application. i can use localization file located in main application. i can not use localization file located in my library. how can i use localization files located in references library?

i use both;

```
Console.WriteLine (NSBundle..MainBundle.LocalizedString("test","");
Console.WriteLine (NSBundle..MainBundle.LocalizedString("test","","Library"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I see two periods in you code.
Secondly, did you set the build action to "Content"?